# Point me in the direction of developing new forum features?

Tags: nodes

Probably the most confusing part about Drupal for a beginner (read: Me!) is figuring out which modules should be used to develop new functionality. I'm looking for the path I would need to take to develop the specific functionality I'm trying to create.

This is what I'm looking to accomplish:

-Attach a user created "idea" or "opinion" to a forum post or thread

-Allow users to vote on & modify these "ideas" and "opinions"

Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: what research have you done ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a forum in drupal, you can start with the forum module. It is a core module, so it will already be installed. The following steps can make forum development simpler:

1. Enable the module-

   - Go ahead and navigate to Site Building>>Modules and check the box next to forums to enable the module.
2. Set up containers-

   - you need to navigate to administer >> forums to start setting up your new forum
3. Set up forums-

   - Each container "contains" several forums. In other words, your
     containers are children of the root node and your forums are children of
     your containers
4. Customize your forum for adding content or ideas-

   - The following modules can be used for content entry:

     - [BUEditor](http://drupal.org/project/bueditor) or [wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg)
     - [Live](http://drupal.org/project/live)
     - [Quote](http://drupal.org/project/quote)
     - [Smileys](http://drupal.org/project/smileys)
     - [Signatures for Forums](http://drupal.org/project/signature_forum)
     - [Comment Upload](http://drupal.org/project/comment_upload)
5. In order to add the voting/rating features, use the following:

   - [VotingAPI](https://drupal.org/project/votingapi)
   - [Rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate)

Advanced Forum may also be used if you wish to enhance Drupal's core forum module features.